# What users need write access on App_Data folder for Elmah to write the error files

Tags: elmah

I have published my site and an exception is thrown but no error files are generated in the App_Data folder. I am wondering whether its write access to the folder.

The documentation says the ASP.Net process needs write access but not sure what is meant by that.  Can someone tell me which user needs rights to this folder?

Thanks

**UPDATE:** I have found that the ASP.Net process on Win 2003 is the user NETWORK SERVICE.  Is that correct?

Comment: awesome, this is the exact question I came here to ask!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows Server 2003 (IIS6+) and higher it is NETWORK SERVICE. On IIS 5 and below it is the ASPNET user account that needs the required access.

Answer (score 2):

It's whatever user is the identity of the application pool your app is running in.  Typically this will be Network Service, but it could be a different account if your hosting administrator has set it up that way.